# Error: Method eth_compileSolidity not supported

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

ENV:
test-rpc
truffle

code:
let source = "pragma solidity ^0.4.11;contract Calc{   uint count;  function add(uint a, uint b) returns(uint){    count++;    return a + b;  } function getCount() returns (uint){    return count;  }}";

let calc = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

The terminal tell me:
truffle(development)> Error: Error: Method eth_compileSolidity not supported.
at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:101870:16)
......

Comment: I am not sure if its deprecated.. please check the link below  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/209 . If you want to get ABI / binaries of your contract,you could use remix.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you trying to obtain ABI and/or bytecode of your contract.
Web3 library (which you require in truffle console and then instantiating web3 provider) has no web3.eth.compile.solidity() since version 1.6.0

Here described compiling ways using Remix and solc compiler: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-to-compile-solidity-contracts-with-geth-v1-6

When truffle compiles your code it uses some fixed version of solc (depending on truffle version). For truffle 3.2.5 solc 0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.Emscripten.clang used. Here's the way how to get current version of  truffle's solc (it's neccessary to know when you [verifying code](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2) on Etherscan): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/how-do-i-find-the-exact-solidity-compiler-version-used-by-truffle